# How to properly use ScriptReference and Nuget

Tags: nuget

I am using nuget to update my packages. As an example I use it to get the latest releases of JQuery.

In my MasterPage I have the following:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" EnablePartialRendering="True">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"/>
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

I just used Website -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Update. Nuget updated to jquery-3.0.0. When it did this it removed the jquery-2.2.3 files from my scripts folder and replaced them with the jquery-3.0.0 files.

I thought that it would also automatically update the ScriptReferences in my project, but it doesn't.

Is there not a way that this can be automatically updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, NuGet by itself does not so that. It is up to the package author, in this case JQuery should define the sort of transformations that need to happen on package install.

In most cases, we would actually recommend packages dont modify projects because this is inherently unstable since the state of the project can vary significantly and it is hard for package authors to write something that works 100% of time when you install and uninstall packages.

Comment: What is the etiquette here? Should I rename the files to e.g. jquery.min.js and alter the references, so all I do is rename the new files. Or should I keep the file names to reflect the version number and change the references?

Comment: @Family you should update the script reference to point to the new files. You could run into issues with a future update otherwise.